# bootstrap 4.3 nav-item selected cannot make bottom border transparent

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

Am trying to make the bottom line tab become transparent (blue here) when the tab is selected.

On the picture below it works on the "active" state, when I click, but once selected, the tab still show the blue lie at the bottom, cf. second picture.

Below is my CSS code.

```
.tab-pane {
    border-left: 3px solid #ff6a00;
    border-right: 3px solid #ff6a00;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ff6a00;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.nav-item {
    background-color: #efefef;
    border-left: 3px solid #007BFF;
    border-right: 3px solid #007BFF;
    border-top: 3px solid #007BFF;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #007BFF;
}
    .nav-item:active {
        border-bottom-color: transparent;
    }

    .nav-item:current {
        border-bottom-color: transparent;
    }

.nav-tabs {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post a sample of the HTML too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the .active class is set on `nav-link`, the custom borders should also be set on `nav-link`...

```
.nav-tabs .nav-link {
    background-color: #efefef;
    border-left: 3px solid #007BFF;
    border-right: 3px solid #007BFF;
    border-top: 3px solid #007BFF;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #007BFF;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-link.active {
    border: 3px solid #007BFF;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/hXw0dtGf9W)